# Trying to understand ESR

Tags: esr

New here, self taught, been working with tube amps for a while. Currently working on my 64 Deluxe Reverb that I have restored to stock, with some of the original ceramic and film capacitors. Just received an ESR02 to test capacitors. I still cannot wrap my mind around exactly what ESR affects in these old circuits. The ceramics are used for coupling, electrolytic's for bypass and filtering. My question is what does the ESR affect. If I find say 1.5 ohms ESR on a component, what exactly does that affect? Obviously in a grounded cap, 1.5 to ground would not be too good, so how should I view ESR, the way it gives up it's capacitance, or passes voltage in the coupling, lowered voltage to the next? These parameters change the tone, feel, and response of the amp as I have tried substitution. Still a bit hard to comprehend.  To me capacitance is the most difficult thing to understand, and yes I have read much about it.

Answer (score 1):

ESR is effective *series* resistance.  A cap with a 1.5\$\Omega\$ ESR acts like it's in series with a 1.5\$\Omega\$ resistor.  In a tube amp, that probably means nothing (look at the values of all the other resistors in the thing -- if they're involved with the signal path then they probably range from 20k\$\Omega\$ to 2M\$\Omega\$).

Note that it's "effective" series resistance.  It's what the capacitor *acts like*.  And because it's in series with the capacitive element, it doesn't matter whether the reality is that some joker has put a resistor inside the capacitor body, or that there's 100 little resistors in series with 99 little caps -- the *behavior* of the part will be the same, or that the electrolytic goo that makes one plate of the capacitor has some resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzLSYz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: One thing it means is for a given ripple voltage, the cap with higher ESR will dissipate more power, heat itself up more, and, all else being equal, fail sooner.

Comment: Okay, so if the capacitance is there on spec within toleramce, higher esr than spec won;t affect it much at all.

Comment: I am still baffled, thus I must view it as resistance within the capacitance - or a resistor on either side  of the capacitor in series. Makes no sense.

Comment: The key word in ESR is "effective".  It describes *how the thing acts*, not *what it is*.

Comment: Sheesh, I think these old ceramics are bad, will get back in there tomorrow. I always thought they last forever, maybe not, tested a few I took out of the vibrato circuit.

Comment: @ Barry let us know what you discover with these old components, please.

Comment: try reading more https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A17574+esr+  ESR is the resistance of each electrode interface to an insulation dielectric

Comment: From what I read again, it is the complex form of ohms law expressed as Z derived from all factors. I can accept that. One of the .02uf old ceramics tests 14.71nf with a vloss of  .3% on the ESR02 Bside. Seems low and more resistivity.

Comment: I don't know how to intrerpret vloss yet. Just went back into the chassis and tested many in circuit. Some seem spot on, but with vloss indicated. Some don't seem right, so I will remove those and test. The Bside esr02 seems to be correct, quite a microprocessor in there, still don't know why the standalone capacitor function only works for electrolytics. Going back to the auto find transistor function works for all others though. The .1 brown (mylar I think) coupling reads .2 in circuit with a esr 0f 51-60ohms and vloss of 2.5%. I will start with that one taken out. Thks for everyone's help.

Comment: The Esr02 is a great tool. The mylar was okay, some vloss but acceptable. The main final touches were the red ceramics, replaced the .02 with a white Mallory .022 film, and reverb coupling ceramic with a Xicon. Still have a few more red ceramic Pf to replace as they test out of tolerance. Strangely enough the yellowish ceramics test ok. All the blue molded caps test okay to, so all original from 64. All new F@T electrolytic's throughout, out of spec resistors with new carbon comps, wiring meticulously gone through, entire chassis cleaned, especially under the brass ground plate.

Comment: Grand and glorious sound, Jenson c12k at the moment.

Comment: When you're comparing capacitor values to their marked values, keep in mind that capacitors can vary tremendously from their marked values.  It's called tolerance, and \$\pm\$20% is pretty pretty good for older caps (so, \$\pm\$4nF for a 20nF cap).  Circuit designers would have taken this into account -- there's a lot of places in a circuit where you just need a capacitance to be higher than some value, so more than nominal is just icing on the cake.

Comment: Don't expect in-circuit measurements of values to be at all accurate.  *This is an opinion*, but if you're going to go to the trouble to take a cap out of circuit to measure it, you may as well take it out and replace it with new.

Comment: The more I listen, the more I think the piezoelectric ceramics were the magic of the AB763, the films are more pure, but lose some of that extra vibe - built in effect pedal before they were invented, guess it all what you want out the amp in the end..

Answer (score 1):

The effective series resistance essentially makes the capacitor less ready to accept or release charge

When a voltage change would normally cause an immediate high current in a capacitor, with elevated ESR, some of the voltage change initially hits the ESR so a lower current flows for a longer time.

If a capacitor is like a balloon, capacitor with high ESR is like a balloon that has a constriction in the neck making it harder to get air in or out